# Convert a list to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Sample data:

```
ht <- list(c("word1","word2"),c("number1","number2"))
```

First, `strsplit()` requires comma, but I'm failing to insert comma between the strings.

I have tried something like;

```
lapply(ht, function(x) paste("",",",x)
```

Anyway, the desired output:

```
  Words   Numbers
1 word1   number1 
2 word2   numner2
```

where `Words` and `Numbers` are column names.

EDIT: This is what I came up with, but in one column.

```
seplist <- lapply(splitString, function(x) paste(shQuote(x, type="cmd"), collapse=","))
unls <- data.table(unlist(seplist))
head(unls)
```

How could I proceed from here to the desired outcome?

EDIT 2: The data I have look like this:

```
      [[1]]
 [1] "WIELANDER, s.r.o."                       "Milochov 223  01706   Považská Bystrica"

[[2]]
 [1] "Vojenský technický ústav, a.s."          "kpt. Nálepku  03101   Liptovský Mikuláš"

[[3]]
 [1] "Property Service, s.r.o."   "Dlhá  25A  90031   Stupava"
```

Comment: Based on your EDIT 2, shouldn't your example be transposed: `ht <- list(c("word1","number1"),c("word2","number2"))` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!I'm getting columns and not rows with the solutions provided. Would be here easy fix for the suggested solutions bellow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the fact that a data.frame in R is a list of atomic vectors (each column = separate list item). This means that you almost have what you want.

```
structure(as.data.frame(ht), names=c('Words', 'Numbers'))
##   Words Numbers
## 1 word1 number1
## 2 word2 number2
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 3`, any idea? Of course it works with the sample data...so hence correct

Comment: In case of your "pekne slovenske miesta" a.k.a. Edit 2 example, I think it will suffice to provide 3 (and not 2) labels for `names=...`.

Comment: This is first what I have tried. The 3 labels doesn't solve it. With your solution, I'm getting the solution columnwise.

Comment: Given the sample data provided, the solution is correct so hence the acceptance. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
> ht <- list(c("word1","word2"), c("number1","number2"))
> x <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, ht))
> names(x) <- c('Words', 'Numbers')
> x
  Words Numbers
1 word1 number1
2 word2 number2
```

Of course, this would be even more simple if `ht` was a *named* list.

```
> ht <- list(Words = c("word1","word2"), Numbers = c("number1","number2"))
> data.frame(do.call(cbind, ht))
  Words Numbers
1 word1 number1
2 word2 number2
```

Comment: Same here: I'm getting this error: `number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)`, any idea?

Comment: What other code are you putting in there?  Try it just pasting either of the chunks above.

Comment: Each vector (column) of the dataframe has to have the same number of elements. You may be trying to join vectors of different lengths (which is possible in a list) into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply`,`do.call` and `unlist`

```
df<-do.call(cbind,lapply(ht,function(x) data.frame(x=unlist(x),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)))
names(df)<-c("Words","Numbers")
> df
  Words Numbers
1 word1 number1
2 word2 number2
```